# Changing Users Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using the MVC4 Internet Application and I am trying to change the account model to use my context. I cannot seem to get it to work. I tried to delete the context and include the user profile in my context and I could log on etc but when I check for profiles by user id it returns a null value.

```
public DbSet<FightCard> FightCards { get; set; }
public DbSet<Fight> Fights { get; set; }
public DbSet<Fighter> Fighters { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to do this:

```
public ActionResult Profile(int id)
    {
        UserProfile profile = uc.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        ViewBag.Name = profile.UserName;
    }
```

I get a null value return. Anyone know how to successfully use the simple membership with a different context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it there. But to be honest I'm not exactly sure what fixed it. Here is the link I used and one part of it solved my problem.

http://dansgreenshoes.com/2013/03/10/mvc4usertable/

Comment: just started from scratch and fixed it.